# function execution problem when called, python

Tags: python

I have a small python program to edit a row only in a csv file, I do this by getting all the rows and columns of the file and replacing the selected row with what the user entered.

The point is that I have a function that is activated depends on which row has been selected but it cannot be activated, I have already tried many ways, I have already called it clearly and this function is not executing yet.

I already have the code but I just need to activate the function.

This is a small example of my code:

```
import pandas as pd

my_variable = "ninguna"

new_variable1 = "hello"
new_variable2 = "How are you"
new_variable3 = "brother"

if my_variable == "none":
    with open("priv/productos.csv", 'r') as edit:
        edit = edit.read()
    def edit_row(self):
        def tryloc(df, col, idx, default=None):
            try:
                return df.iloc[col, idx]
            except IndexError:
                return default
        print("the variable if it is running")
        edit = pd.read_csv("priv/products.csv")
        
        product_2 = tryloc(edit, 1, 0)
        brand_2 = tryloc(edit, 1, 1)
        price_2 = tryloc(edit, 1, 2)
        
    
        with open("priv/products.csv", 'w') as login_main:
            login_main.write("PRODUCTS" +",")
            login_main.write("BRANDS" +",")
            login_main.write("PRICES" +"\n")
            
            login_main.write(str(new_variable1) +",")
            login_main.write(str(new_variable2) +",")
            login_main.write(str(new_variable3) +"\n")
        
            login_main.write(str(product_2) +",")
            login_main.write(str(brand_2) +",")
            login_main.write(str(price_2) +"\n")
                  
        edit_row(self)
```

When I run the program everything works except the function :(

Does anyone know what this problem is?
Thank you

Comment: I see some problems that may be indentation, but it seems that you are calling the function `edit_row` from inside the function. Also defining a function inside an `if` statement is not good practice and it is strange that you call the function argument of `self` when it is not a class.

Answer (score 0):

Your function have to be written before your condition. Inside the condition should be only `edit_row(data)` and this will be a call of your function. Also `self` is something that you can use in functions when you define Classes (I don't see classes in your code). Also I don't understand why did you include one function inside another one. What it will return in the case of error. What is `default`?
Call of function have to be outside of function.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend laying out your code more like this:

```
import pandas as pd

def edit_row(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as edit:
        data = edit.read()
        # lines to edit data here
    # lines to save edited data here

edit_row("priv/productos.csv")
```

What you have right now is that my_variable contains the string 'ninguna' and the lines to define and call edit_row() only execute if my_variable contains the string 'none'. So when you run your code, the definition and call to edit_row() are all skipped.

Your code also assumes that edit_row() is a method on an object named edit whose class is never defined. For that to work, you'd need to define a class with edit_row() as a method. For now, just go procedural.